# Is there any way to use formtastic in activeadmin batch action form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

According to activeamdin document, we can do:

```
batch_action :flag, form: {
type: %w[Offensive Spam Other],
  reason: :text,
  notes:  :textarea,
  hide:   :checkbox,
  date:   :datepicker
} do |ids, inputs|
  # inputs is a hash of all the form fields you requested
  redirect_to collection_path, notice: [ids, inputs].to_s
end
```

However, the above form is not formtastic and doesn't support advanced table configuration(set the size for the form window). Is there any way that I can change it to formtastic format like:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
  f.inputs          # builds an input field for every attribute
  f.actions         # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.  The form is built in [batch_action_form.rb](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/6b8c072cca8478277aebc22a1a467a1f9de340f4/lib/active_admin/batch_actions/views/batch_action_form.rb) but rendered dynamically by the front end in [modal_dialog.js.coffee](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/6b8c072cca8478277aebc22a1a467a1f9de340f4/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/lib/modal_dialog.js.coffee), which is currently using jQuery.  It is possible to get creative [rewriting batch action forms](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3965) but I can't recommend it.  If your batch actions are complex try seeing if [Custom Pages](https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html) can meet your needs.